# How to get the subelement of child using Python's ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

The XML looks more less like this:

```xml
<root>
<course>
   <reg_num>10577</reg_num>
   <subj>ANTH</subj>
   <crse>211</crse>
   <sect>F01</sect>
   <title>Introduction to Anthropology</title>
   <units>1.0</units>
   <instructor>Brightman</instructor>
   <days>M-W</days>
   <time>
       <start_time>03:10PM</start_time>
       <end_time>04:30</end_time>
   </time>
   <place>
       <building>ELIOT</building>
       <room>414</room>
   </place>
</course>
<root>
```

Then here is my code to get the title and such....And I would like to get the time or the place tag which have a child element. How can I do that, and I also tried different methods but none of them seem to works. Thank you! Any help is appreciated

```python
for c in courses:
    title = c.find('title').text
    num = c.find('crse').text
    days = c.find('days').text
    # time = c.find('time').text

    # for t in c:
    #     timeSlot1 = t.find('start_time')
    #     timeSlot2 = t.find('end_time')


        # format text using {}
        print(' *{} {} [{}] {} {} {}'.format(b, title, days, num, timeSlot1, timeSlot2))


    # how to get date
```

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there: just select the correct child by specifying a path relative to `<course>`:

```
for c in courses:
    title = c.find('title').text
    # [...]

    timeSlot1 = c.find('time/start_time').text
    timeSlot2 = c.find('time/end_time').text
```

Comment: thank you so much! I would definitely upvote this if I have more reputation!